# Matplotlib : why plot save from jupyter notebook and from Python code are different?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart

I have written a jupyter notebook python script to analyze data and save an image with a bar chart. At the end, I decide to clean my code and create a python script in .py file. However, the plots from my notebook and the plots from my .py file are totally different!

How can I reproduce the same bar chart in my .py file?

Thanks in advance.

**NB :**

- I'm on Linux.
- below, my  function which is the same in the notebook and the .py file

```
def dict_bar_plot(data, widh_inch = 20, heigh_inch = 10, title = "", save_fig=False, save_name = "default", show_fig=False):
    names = list(data.keys())
    values = list(data.values())

    bar_container = plt.bar(range(len(data)), values, tick_label=names, color="#F9D1E4")
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    
    labels = [val if val > 0 else "" for val in bar_container.datavalues]    
    plt.bar_label(bar_container, labels=labels)
    
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = widh_inch,heigh_inch
    if save_fig:
        plt.savefig(PLOTS_PATH + "/" + save_name + ".png")
        
    plt.title(title)

    if show_fig:
        plt.show()
```

Comment: it's possible that the notebooks and the scripts are ending up using different a dpi. Try adding `dpi=300` as an arguement to your `plt.savefig` command. Or alternatively set `plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 300`. You might also need to put that (and the `figsize` one) before the figure is created with `plt.bar`.

Comment: @tmdavison thank you ! The problem was 
```plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = widh_inch,heigh_inch``` is placed after plt.bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written by @tmdavison the problem was `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = widh_inch,heigh_inch` is placed after plt.bar